# How does aggregate production function shift by an increase in average and marginal productivity of labour?

Tags: production-function

Increasing productivity would mean increase in output for each given amount of labour employed, resulting in an upward shift of production function as shown below. However I'm unable to understand the difference in impact of higher marginal and average productivity of labour, taken separately. Will it just be a difference in amount of upward shift with no qualitative difference?

[image]